# Error The constructor Family(String, String, int) is undefined

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java. I am getting an error "The constructor Family(String, String, int) is undefined". Im not sure what this means. Need a bit of help here please.

EDIT: I was missing the extra 3 parameters and also was missing quotes around 31.

Main.java

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Family person = new Family("CHRIS", "PEREZ", 31);
    String person1 = person.getPerson();
    System.out.println(person1);    
}

}
```

Family.java

```
public class Family {

String firstName;
String lastName;
int age;
int phoneNumber;
String dob;
String married;

public Family(String firstName, String lastName, int age, int phoneNumber,
        String dob, String married) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.married =  married;


public String getPerson() {
    return ("Hi my name is"+this.firstName+" "+ this.lastName+"."+"I am "+this.age+" years old.");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `Family` class constructor like this:

```
Family person = new Family("CHRIS", "PEREZ", 31);
```

But the only constructor in the class is defined like this:

```
public Family(String firstName, String lastName, int age, int phoneNumber,
    String dob, String married) {
```

See that it has more parameters than you're passing in: `phoneNumber, dob, married`. In Java you have to give values to all parameters:

```
Family person = new Family("CHRIS", "PEREZ", 31, 123456, "5/Apr/1975", "who's asking");
```

Or, you need to define a new constructor that needs only firstName, lastName and age.

Comment: Thank you. I included the rest the parameters but still getting that error.

Comment: Same exact error.  Does it matter i have to different files? a Family and a Main one?

Comment: So you're getting an error that says `Family(String, String, int) is undefined` from a line of code that calls the 6-parameter constructor? That's unlikely. The very least the error is different

Comment: The constructor Family(String, String, int, String, String, String) is undefined. It added the extra three parameters i was missing.

Comment: You're passing `String` for phone number, like `"(555) 123-456"` but the method declaration has `int` so it can only accept numbers like 555123456. It probably should be string

Comment: Yea i changed that when i replied. I made them all a string except age but didnt make a difference. Im probably making some newbie error somewhere.

Comment: Try deleting all compiled class files, it's possible one of the classes is not getting recompiled despite having changed the source file

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `Family` class only has a six-argument constructor requiring all of the six fields to be provided. Your call:

```
Family person = new Family("CHRIS", "PEREZ", 31);
```

only provides three of the six required. You could override the constructor, for instance:

```
public Family(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    ...
}
```

but you should do something with the rest of the fields that you didn't provide here that you provide in the other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when calling the constructor arguments in the wrong order that you specified them in.